# Show that there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for any continuous periodical function then it has as its only periodical solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $B(t)$ be continuous and periodical of period $\tau$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $x′ = B(t)x$ has $\varphi \equiv 0$ as the only periodic solution of period $\tau$. **Show that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for any continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, periodic of period $\tau$ in the first variable with $\vert D_2f(t,x) \vert < \delta$ for all $(t, x)$, then $x′ = B(t)x + f(t, x)$ has as its only solution $\varphi_f$ of period $\tau$.**

I am just starting the course of theory of ordinary differential equations and they have left us this exercise of which I have no theory, please someone who can help me by explaining me or with a book, I would appreciate it.

Comment: If $x(t;x_0)$ is the solution to $x(0;x_0)=x_0$, then the task is to show that $x_0\mapsto x(τ;x_0)$ has only one fixed point.

The general idea is that if you have a function with exactly one "regular" fixed point, as here with $f=0$, then any perturbation that is small, not only in value but also in derivative, will not change this qualitative picture. The task is to give a quantitative insight to what "small enough" is for the given situation.

Answer (score 0):

If $x(t;x_0)$ is the solution to $x(0;x_0)=x_0$, then the task is to show that $x_0\mapsto x(τ;x_0)$ has only one fixed point.

The general idea is that if you have a function $g$ with exactly one fixed point not only for $x=g(x)$ but also for $x+c=g(x)$, as here in the linear system with $f=0$, then any perturbation that is nearly constant, that is, small in the first derivative, will not change this qualitative picture. The task is to give a quantitative insight to what "small enough" is for the given situation.

Let $U(t)$ be the matrix function that solves $U'(t)=B(t)U(t)$, $U(0)=I$. Then by the assumptions $A=U(τ)-I$ is invertible. Define a fixed-point iteration as
$$
N(x_0)=x_0-A^{-1}(x(τ;x_0)-x_0)=A^{-1}(U(τ)x_0-x(τ;x_0)).
$$
Then consider $N(x_0)-N(y_0)$ and the corresponding time derivative
\begin{multline}
\frac{d}{dt}[U(t)(x_0-y_0)+x(t;y_0)-x(t;x_0)]
\\=B(t)(U(t)(x_0-y_0)+x(t;y_0)-x(t;x_0)] + f(t,x(t;y_0))-f(t,x(t;x_0))
\end{multline}
For the last term use that the $x$-Lipschitz constant of $f$ is $δ$. Thus with $M_1(t)=U(t)(x_0-y_0)+x(t;y_0)-x(t;x_0)$ and $M_2(t)=x(t;x_0)-x(t;y_0)$ one gets the differential inequalities
\begin{align}
\|M_1'(t)\|&\le \|B(t)\|\,\|M_1(t)\|+δ\|M_2(t)\|\\
\|M_2'(t)\|&\le (\|B(t)\|+δ)\|M_2(t)\|
\end{align}

Via multiple applications of the Grönwall lemma find a Lipschitz constant of $N$ that is proportional to $δ$. Then use a $δ$ so that this Lipschitz constant becomes smaller than $1$. Apply the Banach fixed-point theorem.